# CSS resizing the <div> to fit the text

Tags: css

I have a `<div>` called "container" which wrap another `<div>` called "box".
"box" has text inside it.

The problem is I can't seem to resize the `<div class="box">` to fit the text. I also got a diagram to explain my situation.

[image: figure]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="float.css">
<div class="container">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="box">Hello my name is jack</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="box">Hello my name is jack</div>
</div>
```

My CSS

```css
.container {
    background-color: #ED8713;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 60px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.box {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 270px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-align: center
}
```

Comment: I think the upload picture button is broken because it wouldn't let me display my picture directly

Comment: We finally found the problem, he is using IE.

Comment: @jmendth , I was using firefox but I also wanted it to work for IE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You know what? We're all idiots. Here's the REAL answer:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span class="box">Hello my name is jack</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    background-color: #ED8713;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 60px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
.box {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: can i ask you something , I can't put a border around <p>  , is this true?

Answer (score 4):

Let the `.box` be an `inline-block`...

```
.box {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

...and center it!

```
.container {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Adding this two snippets to your stylesheet and removing the `width: 270px` should suffice.

Comment: @JackRoster what happens if you remove that `margin: 60px` and the `width: 270px`?

Comment: Yep the box is still at the left

Comment: @JackRoster I see it centered. Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/Xm32D/1 *Make sure you're not using IE!* (never use IE :)

Comment: @jmendeth "never use IE" --- Seriously?

Comment: No, please. IE is bad for all of us. Every browser follows the standards *except IE*. Don't use it.

Comment: @Kolink Is that a joke? :) If it isn't: well, if you're using IE 10 it's more acceptable, but this is clearly not the case.

Comment: I'm using IE10, FYI. I updated Firefox to Fx20 today and it's laggier than IE6...

Comment: @Kolink you're using IE 10 (that's better) but the OP's surely not. In fact, Microsoft uses every software he makes to build a monopoly, so I wouldn't even use IE 10.

Comment: @Kolink Not to talk about Windows... ;)

Comment: @Kolink if other people do, it's their problem. We just won't support IE-propietary APIs *again*. :)

Comment: jmendeth can I ask you . Can you put a border around <p>?

Comment: IE doesn't use proprietary APIs anymore. Don't forget who invented things like innerHTML and font embedding ;)

Comment: @Kolink oh yes it will. This could be a starting for one: https://twitter.com/chrismatthieu/status/324894166012289024

Comment: @Kolink they invented them (propietary) and we invented a standard alternative that has taken over. Please, don't trust a company like Microsoft so easily... it's not good for your health ;)

Comment: i see your brilliant at programming . How long have you been programming for?

Comment: @JackRoster since I was 8.

Comment: wow, jmendeth , can you please help me on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139914/jquery-plugin-called-columnizer-not-functioning-properly-on-ie

Comment: @JackRoster the solution is simple: *don't use IE*. OR upgrade to IE 10. Period.

Comment: okay I think I might have to do that but can I ask , why doesn't it work on IE?

Comment: @JackRoster there are some common rules, called *standards*, that all browsers respect. But Microsoft doesn't like common rules. It created his *own* extensions for people to pay for using them.

Comment: @JackRoster but lastly Microsoft has made IE 10, which *does* follow standards.

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the width or set it to auto : `width : auto`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `width` on the `.box`, and add `display:inline-block` instead.

Comment: Okay I did but it pushes the text to the left

Comment: Add `text-align:center` to the container, not the `.box`

Comment: work perfectly but display inline block doesn't work on IE8 . How can we make it work?

Comment: Yes it does. In fact to some extent it even works in IE5.5, but you would need to use a `<span>` tag instead of a `<div>`... but if you're going to use a `<span>`, you don't even need `inline-block`. [Source](http://caniuse.com/#search=inline-block)

Comment: sometime weird , i think you posted your answer twice

Comment: I posted a new answer because it was radically different from this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will stretch the container div to the width of the parent.

```
.box {
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a trick  make the  inner div color invisible with sane background  color as parent div  , now put the text in

```
<span style="background-color:#ffffff;" >Text </span>
```

Comment: What happens then is that the "white" space is no longer a box (to note the difference, put a `<br>` inside the text).

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox update

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="float.css">
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">Hello my name is jack</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">Hello my name is jack</div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #ED8713;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 60px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.box {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 270px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Just display:inline]
Just display:inline,this makes the box fits the text

if you want to center the box, add 'text-align: center' to the outer div