# Jquery plugin called Columnizer not functioning properly on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using a Jquery plugin called Columnizer to layout my text and it works perfectly on firefox  but it doesn't work probably on IE without making a new column and placing them statically.

http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/

With Firefox , it automically arranges the element in column

How can we make it also work on IE? I'm trying really hard and  just not working

[image]

My html

```
   <script type = "text/javascript" src ="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src ="https://raw.github.com/adamwulf/Columnizer-jQuery-Plugin/master/src/jquery.columnizer.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('h1').addClass('dontend');
    $('.wide').columnize({
        width : 120,
        height : 400
    });
});
  </script>

   <script  style="display:none" type="text/javascript">var Mint=new Object();Mint.save=function()
  {var now=new Date();var debug=false;if(window.location.hash=='#Mint:Debug'){debug=true;};var path='http://welcome.totheinter.net/mint/?record&key=6a56784248357a3735323031363633316663796c526d';path=path.replace(/^https?:/,window.location.protocol);for(var developer in this)
  {for(var plugin in this[developer])
  {if(this[developer][plugin]&&this[developer][plugin].onsave)
  {path+=this[developer][plugin].onsave();};};};path+='&'+now.getTime();if(debug){window.open(path+'&debug&errors','MintLiveDebug'+now.getTime());return;};var ie=/*@cc_on!@*/0;if(!ie&&document.getElementsByTagName&&(document.createElementNS||document.createElement))
  {var tag=(document.createElementNS)?document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml','script'):document.createElement('script');tag.type='text/javascript';tag.src=path+'&serve_js';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(tag);}
  else if(document.write)
  {document.write('<'+'script type="text/javascript" src="'+path+'&amp;serve_js"><'+'/script>');};};if(!Mint.SI){Mint.SI=new Object();}
  Mint.SI.Referrer={onsave:function()
  {var encoded=0;if(typeof Mint_SI_DocumentTitle=='undefined'){Mint_SI_DocumentTitle=document.title;}
  else{encoded=1;};var referer=(window.decodeURI)?window.decodeURI(document.referrer):document.referrer;var resource=(window.decodeURI)?window.decodeURI(document.URL):document.URL;return '&referer='+escape(referer)+'&resource='+escape(resource)+'&resource_title='+escape(Mint_SI_DocumentTitle)+'&resource_title_encoded='+encoded;}};Mint.save();</script> 






  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="f.css">



  <div class="container"> <div class="wide">


      <div class="block"> Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello </div><br>
      <div class="block"> Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello </div><br>
      <div class="block"> Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello </div><br>
      <div class="block"> Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello </div><br>
      <div class="block"> Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello </div><br>
      <div class="block"> Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello </div><br>


  </div></div>
```

My CSS

```
  .container {
      background-color: #;
      height: 300px;
      width: 700px;

  }
  .block {
      width: 100px;
      height:150px;
      background-color: #;
      margin: 10px;
      margin-top: 5px;
  }
```

Comment: Can you try adding a `float:left;` to `.block`

Comment: remove `<div class="block">` and just keep plain text inside `wide` class. This should work, the columnizer plugin will add the classes for each block automatically.

Comment: Did you check my answer? did you do try it like that? use firebug to inspect the elements between http://welcome.totheinter.net/autocolumn/sample5.html and your html code.

Comment: @frozenhaart , I did inspect it , they created the columns statically and place each individual elements statically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `<div class="block">` and just keep plain text inside `wide` class. This should work, the columnizer plugin will add the classes for each block automatically.

Eg:

```
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="wide">
     <p>Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello </p>
     <p>Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The Columnnizer will automatically divide the text into different columns.
Like shown below

```
<div class="wide" style="width: 2700px;">
  <div class="first column" style="width: 300px; float: left;">
  <div class="column" style="width: 300px; float: left;">
  <div class="column" style="width: 300px; float: left;">
</div>
```

**New Code**(Paste this code on a Text editor and save it as a HTML page and check the HTML page on IE8 and IE7)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<head>
 <style>
.column *{ padding: 5px; }
</style> 
   <script type = "text/javascript" src ="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src ="https://raw.github.com/adamwulf/Columnizer-jQuery-Plugin/master/src/jquery.columnizer.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('h1').addClass('dontend');
            $('.wide').columnize({
                width : 300,
                height : 200
            });
        });
        </script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper"> 
    <div class="wide">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum ne justo</h1>
 <p>Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello hello Hello  hello Hello  hello HelloHello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello   hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello </p>
     <p>Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello </p>
     <p>Hello  hello HellHello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello o  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello </p>
     <p>Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  heHello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello llo Hello  hello Hello  hello hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello </p>
      <p>Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello </p>
     <p>Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello  hello Hello </p>
    </div>
  </div>
 </body> 
 </html>
```

Comment: http://welcome.totheinter.net/autocolumn/sample5.html check if this demo is working on your IE browser. If it is working use firebug to check the differences between your html code and the demo's html.

Comment: Yeah but you have to create each column statically , in firefox . the columns are created automatically and arrange

Comment: Thank you frozenhaart for helping me . The answer is , IE does not support the plugin

Comment: Please check my updated answer. The code i've show above worked on IE8 and IE7. Please recheck.

Comment: Thank you very much frozenhaart ,:D

Comment: Frozenhart , Whenever I go on IE , why does it ask permission to run activeX? Is their a way to bypass it?

Comment: check this out. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_xp/how-to-stop-permission-to-run-active-x-controls/d7759761-4a89-4097-94dc-eb6d7372d4ae

Comment: I see different users , have different permission thank you frozenharrt

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why this works, but it works for me on IE8: open the browser's console and it will work.

To do that, load the page, Click F12 (open Developer Tools), Click on the script tab, and then on the Console Tab.

Reload the page: it works. You can now close the developer tools window, and all subsequent loads will work as well.